# Java program that deletes a character from a sentence

Tags: java

I am writing a java program that removes a character from a sentence. My code is;

```
public class Ex1Program {

    public void start() {
        String sentence = getSentenceFromUser();
        int randomPosition = getRandomPosition(sentence);
        printCharacterToBeRemoved(sentence, randomPosition);
        String changedSentence = removeCharacter(sentence, randomPosition);
        printNewSentence(changedSentence);
    }

    private String getSentenceFromUser() {
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
        String sentence = Keyboard.readInput();
        return sentence;
    }

    int sentenceLength = sentence.length();
    int randomPosition = (int)(Math.random() * sentenceLength) + 0;
        return randomPosition;
    }

    private void printCharacterToBeRemoved(String sentence, int randomPosition) {
        System.out.print("Removing " + sentence.charAt(randomPosition) + " from position" + randomPosition);
    }

    private String removeCharacter(String sentence, int randomPosition) {
        String changedSentence = sentence.deleteCharAt(randomPosition);
        return changedSentence;
    }

    private void printNewSentence(String changedSentence) {
        System.out.print("New sentence is " + changedSentence);
    }
}
```

I am getting one error message when i compile that says;

> Error: cannot find symbol symbol:   method deleteCharAt(int) location:
>   variable sentence of type java.lang.String

I have spend hours trying to fix this, so help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does String have such a method, `deleteCharAt(int)`? Check the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html If it is not in the API, it does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String` class does not have a `deleteCharAt` method.  The `StringBuilder` has.

Do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence);
String changedSentence = sb.deleteCharAt(randomPosition).toString();
```

I would recommend to use an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse. These development tools would have told you instantly what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

> symbol: method deleteCharAt(int)

Did you look at the API for the String class? Is there such a method?

You can then look at the API by method name to find all the classes that do have a deleteCharAt(...) method.

> I have spend hours trying to fix this, so help would be very appreciated.

The API is your friend. I would start there first when you have a problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

The String class is Java does not contain the method deleteCharAt.
You can make your own (my version is slightly different than the real one):

```
public String deleteCharAt(String str, int pos)
{  
    try
    {    
        return str.substring(0, pos - 1) + str.substring(pos + 1, str.length());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` does not have a method named `deleteCharAt`.

1. Always have the Java 7 Javadoc page available in your browse so you can look up things like this.  It's at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
2. Also, trust your IDE, assuming you are using one. When you typed `sentence.`, did the IDE show you a selection of methods to insert? You would not have seen that method.
3. While you have the Javadoc and the IDE available, browse it.  You'll see that there are methods already available that can simplify what you were doing.  `Random` has `nextInt(int)`, for example.
4. There is no Keyboard class in Java. If you aren't using a class made for your problem, use `java.io.Console`.
5. You do not have to compute a value and return it in another statement.  You can consolidate the last two in:

   private String getSentenceFromUser() {
       System.out.print("Enter a sentence :");
       String sentence = Keyboard.readInput();
       return sentence;
       // Instead, use
       // return Keyboard.readInput();
   }